# Using rspec to test ActionMailer with should_receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have an RSpec test like this:

```
it "should ..." do
  # mailer = mock
  # mailer.should_receive(:deliver)
  Mailer.should_receive(:notification_to_sender)#.and_return(mailer)

  visit transactions_path
  expect do
    page.should_not have_css("table#transactions_list tbody tr")
    find('#some_button').click
    page.should have_css("table#transactions_list tbody tr", :count => 1)
  end.to change{Transaction.count}.by(1)
end
```

If I remove the commented pieces at the top, the test passes.  But with the commented sections in place (how I'd expect to write it) the test fails.

I got the commented pieces off some of googling around the net, but I don't really understand what it's doing or why this fixes it.  It seems like there should be a cleaner way to test emails without this.

Can anyone shed some light?  Thanks!

I'm using rails 3 and rspec-rails 2.10.1

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an instance of Mailer to receive notification_to_sender not the class. From the Rails API

> You never instantiate your mailer class. Rather, your delivery instance methods are automatically wrapped in class methods that start with the word deliver_ followed by the name of the mailer method that you would like to deliver. The signup_notification method defined above is delivered by invoking Notifier.deliver_signup_notification.

Therefore I would use

```
Mailer.any_instance.should_receive(:notification_to_sender)
```

Also, if you need to get the last delivered message, use

```
ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
```

I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure why, but it still seems to fail :/  error shown does not seem to make sense (from a different line) but when I comment the should_receive line it works again.  Oh well..moving on to bigger problems at the moment.

Comment: The ActionMailer API actually changed from `Mailer.deliver_notification_to_sender` in Rails 2.x to `Mailer.notification_to_sender.deliver` in Rails 3.0. Given that change, delivery instance methods are no longer wrapped in class methods since without the deliver call you get back an instance of `Mail::Message`

Answer (score 2):

You're likely calling `Mailer.notification_to_sender.deliver` in your controller, or better yet, a background job. I'm guessing notification_to_sender probably takes a parameter as well.

Anyways, when you call the `notification_to_sender` method on Mailer you're getting back an instance of `Mail::Message` that has the `deliver` method on it. If you were simply doing `Mailer.notification_to_sender` without also calling `deliver`, you could run what you have there with the comments and all would be fine. I would guess you're also calling `deliver` though.

In that case your failure message would be something like

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass
```

That is because `nil` is Ruby's default return value much of the time, which Rails also inherits. Without specifying the `mailer = mock` and `.and_return(mailer)` parts, when the controller executes in context of the test then notification_to_sender will return nil and the controller will try to call `deliver` on that nil object.

The solution you have commented out is to mock out `notification_to_sender`'s return value (normally `Mail::Message`) and then expect that `deliver` method to be called on it.